# html5 Collision detection with moving player on degrees

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, collision-detection

I have my player object and collision object

```
var player = new Object();
player = {
x: window.innerWidth/2,
y: window.innerHeight/2,
width: 30,
height: 59,
aimAngle: 0,
speed: 5,
color: 'red',
};

var collision_object = new Object();
collision_object = {
x: 1080,
y: window.innerHeight/2+100,
width: 50,
height: 100,
color: 'yellow'
};
```

I define the distance in x,y coordinates between player and mouse

```
var mouseX;
var mouseY;
function handleMouseMovePlayer(e) {
mouseX = e.clientX - document.getElementById('canvas').getBoundingClientRect().left;
mouseY = e.clientY - document.getElementById('canvas').getBoundingClientRect().top;
mouseX -= player.x;
mouseY -= player.y;
mouseX = mouseX - player.width/2;
mouseY = mouseY - player.height/2;
}
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMovePlayer(e);});
```

I move player by the help of this formula

```
// search the angle
player.aimAngle = Math.atan2(mouseX,mouseY) / Math.PI * 180;

// function for making player move
function move_player() {
player.x+=Math.sin(player.aimAngle/180*Math.PI) * player.speed;
player.y+=Math.cos(player.aimAngle/180*Math.PI) * player.speed;
}
```

When onmouse down I raise variable called mouseDawn to one, and this function creating interval of move_player function to make it move, and clear the interval when mouse unpressed, so the player stops

```
// on MOUSE DAWN EVENT
if (mouseDown==0) {
    document.body.onmousedown = function() {
        mouseDown++;
        if (mouseDown==1) {
            intervalID = setInterval(move_player,40);
        }
    };
}
```

I was trying a lot difference collision types and none of it helps. For example this if statements checks collision between player and collision objects right, but I don't know what code should I type to make player stops (but not clear the interval)

```
if (player.x < collision_object.x + collision_object.width &&
player.x + player.width > collision_object.x &&
player.y < collision_object.y + collision_object.height &&
player.y + player.height > collision_object.y) {
// I WAS TRYING THIS
player.speed = 1;
player.x-=1;
player.y-=1;
// this
player.x = collision_object.x - player.width;
}
```

But all the variants mentioned above works only for ONE side x or y. If I make the code for both side (going player from left to right and from right to left to collision object) The code just make +1 -1 logic and do nothing visualy.

Comment: may I suggest using an external collision detection lib? I recently wrote this one https://github.com/ronenness/SSCD.js, but honestly there are many great libs you can pick from (like sat.js), and there's no reason to implement it by yourself. unless its for educational purposes :)